# Ng Build --prod takeing nearly 2 hours to build the full project

Tags: angular, angular9, ng-build

I enabled benchmarking from webpack and saw that `AngularCompilerPlugin._emit.ng.gatherDiagnostics.ng.getNgSemanticDiagnostics` takes 1:59:25.180 hours to run.

I don't know what started this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How many packaged are you using in your project? I thing it is some issues in your angular.json file configuration and some issues in the configuration